# Running java application from usb

Tags: javafx, maven-2, usb-drive, maven-shade-plugin, uberjar

I am trying to build a cross platform (vista, xp, mac, Linux). 
I need to put the application in the USB drive formatted in FAT-32 and it should run on any OS computers.
Planning to use Java/JavaFx to do it.

Any advice how we can run on the multiple platforms.

Hi, Can anyone advice use of uber-jar for the above requirment. Would that be good fit.

Comment: just make a jar file. then for ***most*** of the programs you can run the jar file in any OS.

Comment: Java is cross platform ! It converts file to byte code, which can be understood by the Java Runtime on any OS !

Comment: Java is already cross platform just it needs JRE of different platforms. so you need just to create a jar it will execute on any jre platform

Comment: I need to develop something like portableApps, which can run on any OS. I'm looking for tool like jPortable, which seems to do only for windows. but I need for linux and mac too.

Answer (score 2):

A few things to take into consideration:

- The USB must be formatted with a filesystem compatible with all the OS you need to work with.
- A Java application would be able to run on any OS that is able to run Java, but each OS needs a different Java runtime. There's a Java runtime for Linux, one for Windows, one for OSX, etc.

My suggestion would be to define which OS you want to support and create launcher scripts for each one of them on the root of the USB. For instance you would have at least a couple like: myapp.cmd (for Windows), myapp.sh (for Linux), etc.

Additionally you may want to have different Java Runtimes in the same USB, so with the launcher scripts you execute your Java application running it with the corresponding JRE in the USB filesystem.

A twist in the launcher script would be to somehow check if the OS has already a JRE available (Like checking for a variable JAVA_HOME in the environment, or checking the output of "java -version") and act accordingly (although, running a Java application from your own JRE would be safer).